# How to turn off hyperindex in memoir?

Tags: hyperref, memoir, indexing

How can I keep hyperref from inserting `|hyperpage` to my `idx` file in memoir?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\xindyindex % The memoir manual mentions this command but it doesn't seem to do anything. 
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref} %hyperindex=false also doesn't seem to do anything.
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Something\index{something}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Is there another option than commenting out `hyperref`?

Comment: you can try `\renewcommand{\hyperpage}[1]{#1}
\printindex`